# How can I Install ActiveX in Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: uac, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server, activex

I am testing Windows 2008 R2 as a desktop OS. But Oa in my company must be installed in it.

Unfortunately the "[Administering the ActiveX Installer Service in Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631688(WS.10).aspx)" document by Microsoft states:

> The ActiveX Installer Service is not included in Windows Server® 2008 R2. If you attempt to install an ActiveX control from your Web browser on a computer running Windows Server 2008 R2, a User Account Control dialog box with a yellow bar will be displayed warning you that the publisher is unknown.

How can I make it work?

Comment: @jazzson: what is "Oa"?

Comment: @Peter - Maybe he means OWA? Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's just a warning. It's been a while since I've seen one, but it just asks you if you want to proceed or not.

Answering "yes" will install the ActiveX control.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded ActiveX manually, and installed it sucessfully in command mode:

```
regsvr32 oatree.ocx
```

System asked me to reinstall it while re-entering application!

So strange!

Comment: So, wait, is this the solution you've found? Or is this an update to the question?